# Call java function which takes double[] as parameter

Tags: java, scala

I am interfacing with a Java library which  takes in a double[] as parameter and add elements to the array. I  tried creating a Scala mutable array with JavaConversions but it is not able to manage this conversion. Any ideas?

Java:

```
 public static double libraryFn(double[] numbers) {
    .....
    numbers[0] = 1.0
 }
```

Scala:

```
def caller() {
     // Does not work
     val myNumbers =  new Array[java.lang.Double](1)
    libraryFn(myNumbers)
 }
```

**Thanks for the responses.** Looking at the library source more closely, it looks like the library has a bug and was not a scala/java issue at all.

Comment: Can you post the code that isnt working?

Comment: Use Array[java.lang.Double]

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940699/passing-java-array-to-scala

Comment: That question is about calling a scala function with Java array. More importantly there is no issue with mutability. What I have is a java function that takes in a double[] and adds a number to the array (out parameter).

Comment: `java.lang.Double` is not Java's `double`. It needs to be `Array[Double]`, in Scala.

Answer (score 5):

I wonder what is this mutable array you speak of. Just use `Array[Double]` -- that *is* the Java `double[]`.

Comment: val myNumbers = Array[Double](10); libraryFn(myNumbers) throws java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: @Parag That's an issue with the array size, not with its type. Also, `Array[Double](10)` creates an array size 1 with 10.0 as its single element. If you want an array of _size_ 10, you should do `new Array[Double](10)`, or use `Array.fill` or similar methods.