# How to pass a 2 dimensional string array from java code to scala.html in play framework?

Tags: java, html, scala, playframework

I have a problem where it gives me an error `"'[' expected but integer literal found"` at initializing the array the string array `"arr[i][j]="string";"` for all my initialization. I want to display this **2D array** in a table in the HTML view.

Comment: Please try `arr(i)(j)="string"`. You can access elements of the array with `()` not `[]`. Also, remember to use the mutable array.

Answer (score 0):

As this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940699/passing-java-array-to-scala) specifies `Java` array maps directly into `Scala` ones.
And also, in `Scala`, to access an element in a `collection`, you need to use the `apply()` method, which is equivalent to the `()`:

```scala
val arr = Array.fill(3,3)("hello")
// Displays
//arr: Array[Array[String]] = Array(
//  Array("hello", "hello", "hello"),
//  Array("hello", "hello", "hello"),
//  Array("hello", "hello", "hello")
//)

val row0 = arr.apply(0)
//Displays
//row0: Array[String] = Array("hello", "hello", "hello")

val row1 = arr(1)
//Display
//row1: Array[String] = Array("hello", "hello", "hello")

val elem11 = row1(1)
//elem11: String = "hello"
```

Here is how you can update an element:

```scala
arr(1)(1) = "string"

arr.map(_.mkString(",")).mkString("\n")
// Displays
//res9: String = """hello,hello,hello
//hello,string,hello
//hello,hello,hello"
```